# GCP - GKE Setup: Error during load balancer auto generation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I have a GCP Internal private IP GKE cluster that has multiple services that we support. I am attempting to setup an ingress to support these multiple services over TLS. This is based on the following GCP documentation located here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress and here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl

Here is my example ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: myns
  annotations:
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal" # Sets for internal IP's
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: service1-api.us.corp
    - secretName: service2-api.us.corp
  rules:
    - host: service1-api.us.corp
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: service1-api-service
            servicePort: 443
    - host: service2-api.us.corp
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: service2-api-service
            servicePort: 443
```

Here is an example of one of the services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1-api-service
  namespace: myns
  annotations:
    #cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app-name: service1-api
spec:
  #type: LoadBalancer
  #loadBalancerIP: 172.28.11.140
  selector:
    app-type: restful-api
    app-name: service1-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
  #type: ClusterIP
```

I have gone through the process of setting up TLS certs inside of secrets. However, when deploying the ingress, I get the following error:

> Error during sync: error running load balancer syncing routine:
> loadbalancer xxxxxxxx-myns-my-ingress-xxxxxxxx does not exist:
> googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target':
> 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/myproject/regions/us-east4/targetHttpsProxies/k8s2-ts-xxxxxxxx-myns-my-ingress-xxxxxxxx'.
> A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and
> VPC as the forwarding rule., invalid

Based on the documentation, since the load balancer is auto-generated, I am at a loss on how to correct this issue.

Comment: _"A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule., invalid"_ - Is this the end of the error message ?

Comment: @mario, To answer your question "yes" It is the end of the message

Answer (score 3):

In the [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#troubleshooting) section is mentioned this:

> Verifying that proxy-only subnet is created before creating Ingress so as to avoid any sync errors while deploying Ingress.

After I create the proxy-only subnet, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/proxy-only-subnets), all started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem even when using `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert`. I can see the `targetHttpsProxies`:

```
$ gcloud compute target-https-proxies list
```

but `describe` fails:

```
$ gcloud compute target-https-proxies describe k8s2-ts-xxxxxxxx-myns-myingress-xxxxxxxx
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.target-https-proxies.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/myproject/global/targetHttpsProxies/k8s2-ts-xxxxxxxx-myns-myingress-xxxxxxxx' was not found
```

That's probably the reason why it all fails.